# Does accelerometer log data in Toyota Camry?

Tags: toyota, camry, acceleration, accident

After car accident (rear end hit) I need data of peak acceleration. Does accelerometer log data in Toyota Camry LE 2015? How to read?

Comment: It might do or it may not, either way you will need the Toyota computer to talk to the car and that is the computer at a dealer not a cheap chinesium reader found on many sites...

Answer (score 2):

Toyota does not publicly acknowledge the existence of flight recorder type data logging. Access to any such data is not available on the Official approved Scan Tool. I have the OEM scanner and have looked for such data and have found no way to access it, if it exists.

It is suspected that most OEM's do record such data but reserve it for their use and hide the data so that it can only be accessed at the corporate level and that the dealers do not have access.